# How do I change the value of a range input by user scroll?

Tags: javascript, html, web, addeventlistener, mousewheel

I want to change the value of an input type range via mouse scroll.

If the user scrolls up, the value of the range increases, and if the user scrolls down, the value decreases.

I found the `wheel` event, but I'm not sure how I can use it to accomplish the task at hand.

By the way, I have `100vh` on the body so I cant manipulate with scroll bar.

Comment: could you share some codes?

Comment: sorry my bad I forgot to approve your comment, thank you very much

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Detect the `wheel` event and check the `deltaY`.

```js
var slider = document.getElementById("range");
slider.addEventListener("wheel", function(e){
  if (e.deltaY < 0){
    slider.valueAsNumber += 1;
  }else{
    slider.value -= 1;
  }
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
})
```

```css
body{
  margin:0;
  width:100%;
}
input{
  width:100%;
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
Hover over the input and scroll up/down

<input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" id="range">
```

Comment: Although this adjusts the slider it does not seem to fire either "input" or "change" on the range control itself.

Comment: Instead of adding or subtracting values numerically, you could also use the item.stepUp() and item.stepDown() methods. This still doesn't solve the issue that Johncl mentioned about firing input or change.

Comment: @Johncl `let event = new Event('change', {bubbles: true, cancelable: true});
      item.dispatchEvent(event);` will dispatch an event to update the real value

Comment: i love this code snippet, short, easy to read and works!

Comment: @Yog thank you! Enjoy your holidays ‍‍‍